# Hide cursor when keyboard hides

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Looked though questions and can't find if there any way to hide cursor when keyboard hides. So there is no method(callback) that keyboard hides?
By the way [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) says that is not a good manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use editText.clearFocus() method to remove cursor.

Comment: When use it? Hmm i just get idea to make TextWatcher for all EditTexts but this way smells bad

Comment: use this when u wanna hide cursor.

Comment: My question is about how to get that moment when android keyboard hiding.

Comment: keyboard will not hide automatically. There must be an action like backbutton or IME button of keyboard etc. If you are hiding key board using keyboard Enter button or Done then use it: editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                editText.clearFocus();
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });

Comment: What if I have two EditTexts and it sends me to first when i say clearFocus()?